# Apply Custom Function by Group and Over a Rolling Time Frame

Tags: r, finance, portfolio

I have some data on stock returns. It includes portfolios for two investors over the same five time months. Both investors own different amounts of the same stock. Those portfolio weights don't change during the months in question.

```
returns_df <- data.frame(
Investor = c("Jane","Jane","Jane","Jane","Jane","Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom"),
Month = c("January","February","March","April","May","January","February","March","April","May"),
Stock_A = c(0.2,0.3,-0.1,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.3,-0.1,0.2,0.4),
Stock_B = c(0.1,-0.3,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.1,-0.3,0.5,0.6,-0.1),
Stock_C = c(0.5,0.7,-0.3,-0.3,0.1,0.5,0.7,-0.3,-0.3,0.1),
Weight_Stock_A = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2),
Weight_Stock_B = c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4),
Weight_Stock_C = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4))
```

I have a custom R function that computes the variance on a portfolio of stocks -

```
lvar <- function(x, weights, na.rm = TRUE) {
      if (missing(weights)) {
        weights <- rep(1, ncol(x))
    }
  
    covmat <- var(x = x, na.rm = na.rm)
    utc <- upper.tri(covmat)
    wt.var <- sum(diag(covmat) * weights^2)
    wt.cov <- sum(weights[row(covmat)[utc]] *
                  weights[col(covmat)[utc]] *
                  covmat[utc])
    variance <- wt.var + 2 * wt.cov
    return(variance)
      }
```

I'd like to compute the weighted portfolio volatility for each investor over three-month rolling windows (January-March, February-April, etc.) rather than over the entire five months.

The following computes the portfolio volatility for the entire five months in the data. How to apply it over three-month rolling windows for each investor? Thank you.

```
library(dplyr)
returns_df %>% 
  reframe(out = lvar(pick(starts_with("Stock")), 
  weights = pick(starts_with("Weight"))), .by = Investor)
```

Comment: You could use `zoo::rollapply`

Comment: Try `library(slider);returns_df %>% reframe(out = slide_dbl(row_number(), .after = 2, .f = \(i) lvar(pick(starts_with("Stock")) %>% slice(i), weights = pick(starts_with("Weight")) %>% slice(i)), .complete = TRUE), .by = Investor) %>% drop_na(out)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(slider)
returns_df %>% 
 reframe(out = slide_dbl(row_number(), .after = 2,
   .f = \(i) lvar(pick(starts_with("Stock")) %>% slice(i),
   weights = pick(starts_with("Weight")) %>% slice(i)), .complete = TRUE), 
  .by = Investor) %>% 
 drop_na(out)
```

Comment: slider works rowwise over data frames rather than colwise (which is unlike purrr) so you can also do `returns_df %>% mutate(lvar = slide2_dbl(pick(starts_with("Stock")), pick(starts_with("Weight")), lvar, .after = 2, .complete = TRUE), .by = Investor, .keep = "unused")`